# From PeopleEditor to ActiveDirectory User

Tags: people-picker, people-search

I have a PoepleEditor and want to get some additional informations of a selected user from AD.
When PoepoleEditor resolves an Entry you have that PickerEntry as result. One member of it is "key" which i probably should use to find the correct user in AD.
I use the DirectorySearcher to search through LDAP. My Problem is that there is no attribute i could use to match the key of PickerEntry.
The Value of PickerEntry.Key is "abtestportal\Chris" where the LDAP attribute "distinguishedName" of that user returns "CN=Chris,OU=DOM,DC=ab,DC=testportal".
The Problem is that DC contains two strings which are concatenated in the key.
Does somebody know how to search?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but I guess you want to extract "abtestportal" from the string "CN=Chris,OU=DOM,DC=ab,DC=testportal".

This could be done with some stringoperations:

```
    private String GetDcString(String input, String start, String end)
    {
        String result = "";
        while (input.IndexOf(start) > -1)
        {
            input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(start) + start.Length);
            if (input.IndexOf(end) > 0)
            {
                result += input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(end));    
            }
            else
            {
                result += input.Substring(0);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String inputstring = "CN=Chris,OU=DOM,DC=ab,DC=testportal";
        String startstring = "DC=";
        String endstring = ",";
        MessageBox.Show(GetDcString(inputstring, startstring, endstring));
        //Messagebox shows "abportal"
    }
```